# Rails is saving a title with 'Hello &' as 'Hello &amp;' why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a title field. When I post to the server I see:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3Le7aLitPd6MzWFeB0ofI9wk1IuhybNswjG9N+KgJJc=", "poll"=>{"title"=>"Hello &"}}
```

Problem is the DB is then saving as:

```
Hello &amp;
```

So later when I output the field on the site it shows up as `Hello &amp;`

What is the right way to handle this? I want entering `&` to be supported but at the same time not allow users to submit html or js tags.

Thanks

Comment: How are you discovering the `&` is saved in the database as `&amp;`? Have you tried connecting directly to the database via the `mysql` or `pgsql` CLI and querying the table?

Comment: We are using the Sanitize gem. Sanitize.clean(self[column.name], Sanitize::Config::RESTRICTED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sanitize.clean` outputs HTML, not plain text so of course your ampersands are converted to their HTML entity form (i.e. `&amp;`). For example, straight from the the [fine manual](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize):

> `Sanitize.clean(html, Sanitize::Config::RESTRICTED) # => '<b>foo</b>'`

So you are, in fact, store HTML snippets rather than pieces of plain text. You should be using

```
<%= raw @thing.title %>
```

to display your titles as they have already been rendered HTML-safe by Sanitize.

Comment: @AnApprentice: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't I use html_safe?

Comment: @AnApprentice: That's a matter of style, `raw` just does `to_s.html_safe` but has the added benefit of poking you in the eye with a reminder that `title` contains HTML.